# Perl/Sed replace all matches in capture group with lowercase version

Tags: php, bash, perl, sed, zsh

I need to replace all of my includes in a php application with their lowercase equivalent. I'm converting a legacy application to Docker, and the application was built in windows.

I have the following regular expression that I have tested

```regex
(include.+)["'](\w+\.php)["'](.*)
```

And I've tried putting this into a one-liner perl command like so

```sh
perl -p -i -e '/(include.+)[\"\'](\w+\.php)[\"\'](.*)/\1\'\L\2\'\E\3/ `find ./ -name *.php`
```

But I get an error

> (Missing operator before 'L2'?)
>   Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "'L2'E3"
>       (Missing operator before E3?)
>   Unknown regexp modifier "/1" at -e line 1, at end of line
>   syntax error at -e line 1, near "/(include.+)[\"](w+.php)"'/1'L2'"
>   Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

I just need to replace the matched string with `$1'{lowercase $2}'$3` But I'm not much of a perl or sed wizard.

**EDIT**

A couple of examples of php include statements

```php
include "something.php";
include_once "something.php";
include("SomethingElse.php");
include ('Something.php');
include_once("something.php");
include_once ("something.php");
```

Comment: In single quotes in bash, backslash doesn't have a special meaning. You can't include a single quote in single quotes. `'/(include.+)["'\'']...`

Comment: Also the `find` command can match case-insensitive file names with `-iname`.

Comment: Can you show a few examples of realistic `include` statements to process?  (For one, what can follow `'name.php'`?)  How can we provide something that will "work" without any test cases? :)

Comment: [edit] your question to show the expected output given your posted sample input.

Comment: @choroba  As a curiosity, apparently one _can_ use bash's `$'...'` quoting (that dollar's for real!) to allow for some `'` inside: `perl -wE$'say "\'hi\'"'` (I found that I have to also escape `'` for it to show, otherwise this is parsed fine but `'` is not printed).

Comment: @zdim: `$'...'` is not single quotes, the dollar turns on the ANSI C escaping rules.

Comment: @choroba I meant to say that with `$'...'` quotes one can use single quotes inside (otherwise not possible, as your comment said).  Is that not right?

Comment: @zdim Yes, but you need to be careful as some combinations of characters now have different meaning (e.g. `\a`, `\b`, etc.)

Comment: @choroba Right, and my comment should've been more careful.  So for completeness: [bash "ANSI-C quoting"](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) (bash feature that they call "ANSI C quoting" but that differs a little from ANSI-C standard)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To lowercase what is in the `include` statement, changing the input file in-place

```
perl -i.bak -wpe's/include.*\K (([\x22\x27]) \w+\.php \g{-1})/\L$1/x;' file
```

Tested using a file with provided `include` statements.

Notes:

- The `include.*` preceding the name under quotes is matched (to identify that line), but then dropped with `\K` so that we don't have to capture and copy it in the replacement part. See "*Lookaround Assertions*" [in Extended Patterns in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for `\K`
- The quotes `"` and `'` are matched using `\x22` and `\x27`, in a character class (it's tricky with literal quotes). The closing quote is then matched using the (relative) [backreference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences) `\g{-1}`, so that it must be the same as the opening one
- The whole `'AbC.php'`, captured first (so in `$1`), is lowercased with [`\L` sequence](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Modifiers). This is one of the few escapes that work in any [interpolated constructs](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)
- Consider adding anchor `/^\s*` (with optional spaces), to only match at string beginning
- The `/x` modifier allows use of spaces (and comments) inside regex, for readability

I added to flags the `.bak` to keep backup and `-w` to print warnings.

Comment: @richbai90 I did have a typo -- had `\27` instead of intended `\x27`.  duh. Fixed

Comment: idk if the sames true in perl but in awk we avoid hex `\x27` in favor of octal `\047` for the reasons discussed at http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: @EdMorton  Interesting, thank you for the comment and for the link. It appears (by awk-manual page linked in your link) that the origin of such `awk` practice goes back to `gawk`, which allowed "runaway" (my term for "_...allows more than two successive hex bytes..._" from the manual) hex sequences, leading to problems.  Apparently not a problem in Perl, where "_... sequence `\x`. This is followed by either exactly two hexadecimal digits forming a number, or a hexadecimal number of arbitrary length surrounded by curly braces._"  [...]

Comment: @EdMorton [...]  The quote above is from "_Hexadecimal escapes_" section in [perlrebackslash](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html). It also seems that it is octal that may turn out less worry-free in Perl, as it's possible for traditional `\123` sequences to be interpreted in unwanted ways (in 5.14+ Perls the `\o{...}` form is safe). This is discussed in section "_Octal escapes_" in `perlrebackslash`, preceding the (quoted) section on hex.

Comment: so adding \L without the /e qualifer makes it lowercase!.. great to know

Comment: @stack0114106  Hello! :))   Yes, that's one of those escapes that work in normal double-quoted strings, like `$lc_var = "\L$var";` (I can't recall the exact documentation page that states that and lists them.  The link I gave make it look like it's just for regex!)

Comment: @stack0114106 I found it -- [in perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators)  (by the end of the section, look for "_... escape sequences ..._")

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**
The accepted answer did solve the problem, the script below also works, keeping it here for posterity sake.

I wasn't able to make @zdim answer work, but borrowing from his answer and some of the comments I was able to get the following command to do what I needed

```sh
find ./ -name *.php -print0 | xargs -0 perl -i.bak -wpe "s/(include.+)[\"'](\w+\.php)[\"'](.*)/\1\x27\L\2\x27\3/"
```